# Highcharts container selection issue on Nexus 7 (4.2.1)

Tags: javascript, android, html, highcharts, cordova

On the nexus 7 when I run a simple Highcharts example, I have the following issue -:

When I touch any area of the chart, the entire chart gets selected (a blue selection color fills the entire chart) shown below.[image]

This issue does not happen when I try it on any other device (such as the Nexus 4).

Also, when I try accessing the highcharts demos from [demo](http://highcharts.com/demo) , the same issue reappears. This is what leads me to believe it has nothing to do with my source code, but has more to do with the device itself.

Does anyone else face this issue? If so, any advice in fixing this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested examples in Nexus 7 device but and all works properly

http://jsfiddle.net/zn6FM/show/

Do you have the newest `Chrome` or you use other browser? Have you tried to update to Android 4.2.2 ?